# Whats the name of this function?

Tags: functions, terminology, math-history

I read this function in an exercise. It looks quit familiar to me, however I do not know its name.

[image]

Whats the name of the $\rho_n$ function and who brought it up first?

Comment: I mean $\rho_n$

Comment: it is connected with the $\beta$-function. In fact $1/\beta$. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $\rho_{n}=B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}n-1\right)^{-1}$. I
do not know a special name for it.